# Creating latex using sage/python not working

Tags: python, latex, sage

I am trying to write some code where the user enters in a expression into a sage/python interactive and then my programs display the integral in latex. For example the user might enter in x^2 or sin(x) as bounds in my program. However,neither of these expressions works. when I use sin(x) as bound the s shows up as a bound but the in(X) shows up in the expression being integrated. when I put x^2 as a bound the integral does not show up and I get the message "Double Exponents use braces to clarify". Yet, when I use x as a bound it is displayed just fine.

```
s = "$\int_{2}^{3}  \int_{4}^{5} {0} \,dxdy = {1} $"

p = s.format(function, result,lower_x_bound,upper_x_bound,lower_y_bound,upper_y_bound)


html("%s" %p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The string LaTeX is currently receiving when you want, say, x^2 as the intended lower bound and x_3 as the intended upper bound is

`\int_x^2^x_3`

LaTeX is going to have trouble with that.  To get your desired output, LaTeX needs to get the string

`\int_{x^2}^{x_3}`

But the braces you've got right now are getting eaten up by the string formatting step.

So try `$\int_{{{2}}}^{{{3}}} ...$`

---

PS: sin(x) should always be put into LaTeX as `$\sin(x)$`.  If you do `$sin(x)$` LaTeX will interpret this as `s` times `i` times `n(x)`, and the formatting will look bad.

Comment: even when the lower bound is not a exponent it does not work

Comment: when I do this the bounds are not dynamic the integral thing the bounds are now the number 2 and 3 and not what 2 and 3 stand for